# SQL subquery in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with payment:

```
worker_id, amount, payed, date
```

Table workers:

```
id, name, lname
```

I need to write SQL that will give me name, lname and sum for jun, july, august, september.

```
Name | Lname | Sum_JUN | Sum_JULY | Sum_AUG | Sum_SEP
```

I'm trying with subqueries but can't do it. Can you help me?

I created SQL (example). I will replace dates in PHP.

```
select w.name, w.lname,
sum(case when p.payed_date between '2014-06-01' and '2014-06-31' then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_june`,
sum(case when p.payed_date between '2014-07-01' and '2014-07-31' then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_july`,
sum(case when p.payed_date between '2014-08-01' and '2014-08-31' then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_august`,
sum(case when p.payed_date between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-31' then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_september`,
sum(case when p.payed_date between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-31' then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_november`
from worker w
left join worker_sum p on(w.id = p.worker_id)
group by w.id
```

Comment: sum for months of which year ? all or current or something else

Comment: Hello Chris. Is there any more table? Like one that contains a month column or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for your desired sum,But this will give you the sum for months from all years exist in your table

```
select w.*,
sum(case when month(p.date) = 6 then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_june`,
sum(case when month(p.date) = 7 then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_july`,
sum(case when month(p.date) = 8 then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_august`,
sum(case when month(p.date) = 9 then p.amount else 0 end) `sum_september`
from workers w
left join payment p on(w.id = p.worker_id)
group by w.id
```

Comment: I will call it from PHP so with some modifications I have what I wanted! Thanks a lot.